# Different Behaviour of defer statement

Tags: ios, swift

I have code on logout button, where I'm using `defer` statement.

I'm wondering when changing position of `defer` statement code inside action method scope.

1. I have added `defer` statement at the end of method, it's show me warning.

> 'defer' statement before end of scope always executes immediately;
>   replace with 'do' statement to silence this warning

**Code:**

```
override func sendButtonTapped(sender: Any) {

    self.deleteCoreData()
    self.clearUserDefaults()

    // Clear view context
    AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.reset()

    ....
    ....

    // Call after all code execution completed in this block's Scope
    defer {
        // Set isUserLoggedIn and change root view controller.
        UserDefaults.Account.set(false, forKey: .isUserLoggedIn)
        AppDelegate.shared.setRootViewController()
    }
}
```

2. Then, I have added `defer` statement at start of method, it's show nothing.

**Code:**

```
override func sendButtonTapped(sender: Any) {

    // Call after all code execution completed in this block's Scope
    defer {
        // Set isUserLoggedIn and change root view controller.
        UserDefaults.Account.set(false, forKey: .isUserLoggedIn)
        AppDelegate.shared.setRootViewController()
    }

    self.deleteCoreData()
    self.clearUserDefaults()

    // Clear view context
    AppDelegate.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext.reset()

    ....
    ....
}
```

Can anyone explain what exactly happening with `defer` statement?

Comment: There is no point in placing it on the end of the function, it is only moving code inside defer there so why?

Comment: Hello Mayur, behavior of the defer changed. Before: defer executed his code after function return. Example: return 1; defer.. Instead of that behavior defer now executes before function return(exit). Exmaple: defer.. return. So compiler just says that it's pointless to put your code in a defer.

Comment: That means, If I put code in `defer`, so it's execute before code outside of `defer` ?

Comment: No, defer always executes before end of the function, before return or like the latest code in your function if there is no 'return'

Comment: Needless to say, one of the key virtues of `defer` is that it makes sure that the deferred block gets called regardless of how you exit the current scope (i.e. if you have any early exits with `return` statements, or what have you). If you don’t have any `return` statements in your code, there’s little benefit to `defer` statements at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum it up, the `defer` statement will be executed at the end of the **scope** you are in. ( .apple doc : https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_defer-statement )

*from apple doc*

```
func f() {
    defer { print("First defer") }
    defer { print("Second defer") }
    print("End of function")
}
f()
// Prints "End of function"
// Prints "Second defer"
// Prints "First defer"
```

The `defer` statement allow you to define an action that will be executed **after** the rest of the operation you want to be done, i.e. at the end of the **scope**.

The warning is pretty explicit too, considering you place the `defer` statement just at the end of the scope, it doesnt serve any purpose :

```
func f() {
    print("TIC")
    defer { print("TAC") } // will be print at the end of the function
}
f()
// Prints "TIC"
// Prints "TAC""
```

which is the very same as :

```
func f() {
    print("TIC")
    print("TAC") // no defer, same result
}
f()
// Prints "TIC"
// Prints "TAC""
```

---

**To go further**

Then why do the warning propose you a `do` block ? 
Actually, the two previous example are not 100% the same, when you use the `defer` statement, it creates its own **scope**

```
func f() {
    // here you are in the scope of the `f()` function
    print("TIC")
    defer { 
        // here you are the scope of the `defer` statement
        print("First defer") 
    }
}
```

And the closest way to *manually* create a scope is the `do` statement

```
func f() {
    // here you are in the scope of the `f()` function
    print("TIC")
    do { 
        // here you are the scope of the `do` statement
        print("First defer") 
    }
}
```

*From apple docs*

> The do statement is used to introduce a new scope and can optionally contain one or more catch clauses, which contain patterns that match against defined error conditions. Variables and constants declared in the scope of a do statement can be accessed only within that scope.

if you want to learn more about scopes, here is some lecture: https://andybargh.com/lifetime-scope-and-namespaces-in-swift/

> Essentially, an objects scope defines the areas of our program from which the item can be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

According to Swift documentation:

> A defer statement is used for executing code just before transferring program control outside of the scope that the defer statement appears in. This means that a defer statement can be used, for example, to perform **manual resource management** such as closing file descriptors, and to **perform actions that need to happen even if an error is thrown**.

In your example, using a `defer` at the end of the code is useless because the code will be executed exactly in the same way as if it was outside the `defer`, as a `defer` executes the code just before exiting the current scope (method).